# Casting sub classes values using Binding in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

I have a class person with the fallowing structure in c#:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string Complement {get;set;}
    public string Number {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public string Estate {get;set;}
    public string Zip {get;set;}
}
//...
public class Person
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
    public string Genre {get;set;}
    public Phones Phone {get;set;}
    public string Birtday {get;set;}
}
```

In my XAML file I have:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- ... -->
      <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Blue"
            FontAttributes="Bold" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Email}"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Orange"
            FontAttributes="Bold" />
      <!-- so, how I can fill this label with all values in address class referenced in person class -->
      <Label Text="{Binding Address.Street + Address.Complement +", " + Address.Number + " - " + Address.City + "..."}"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"
            FontAttributes="Bold" />
      <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

I am noob in Xamarin and c#, someone can help-me to cast the complete address for a person directly binding its parts in a label?
It is possible to make like I sample in my commented code here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine multiple properties together in a binding like that.

The easiest approach would be to add a helper property to your `Address` class

```
public string DisplayAddress {
  get {
    return Street + Complement +", " + Number + " - " + City + "..."; 
  }
}
```

and then bind to that

```
<Label Text="{Binding Address.DisplayAddress}"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Gray"
        FontAttributes="Bold" />
```